# htaccess subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Howto make this with htacess:

```
subdomain.domain.com -> domain.com/subdomain (no redirect on client side)
domain.com/subdomain -> subdomain.domain.com (redirect)
```

I make firs redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) subdomain/$1 [L]
```

How is it inserted in the form htacess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$  index.php/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Are there multiple subdomains?

Answer (score 8):

This is a wildcard based solution, so it sould work for any number of subdomains.

This will redirect `domain.com/foo/bar` to `foo.domain.com/bar`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)(/.*|$) $1.domain.com/$2 [R=302]
```

This will handle (internal rewrite) the virtual hosts:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

You might consider using 301 (permanent redirect) instead of the 302.

I strongly suggest you have a `VirtualHost` for your main site *domain.com* or *www.domain.com* and a separate one for handling the virtual subdomains.

For only a certain subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (subdomain)(/.*|$) $1.domain.com/$2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think he must add *.domain.com subdomain in his cPanel or such for this to work.

Comment: I'm constantly editing the answer. Yes, at one point there must be a `ServarAlias *.domain.com` in a `VirtualHost`.

Comment: Thank you, good decision. How it is done, but only for a subdomain with a specific name (ie, a subdomain only 1)

Comment: I added that to the end of my answer.

Comment: What if /subdomain is real folder in root, will it still redirect to subdomain.domain.com or it will go into infinite loop?

Comment: Thank you very much, one more question, how to be apart of this if I have a htaccess is present instruction:

`RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/ $ 1 [R = 301, L]`

Will not conflict, what the correct order of transformations?

Comment: @Makigator you can insert that after the first rule, I made a bit modification on it so they won't conflict.

Comment: @webarto The first (wildcard) solution assumes that there are no folders on `domain.com`, OR it is handled by a separate VirtualHost than `*.domain.com`. - Infinite loops will never happen.

Comment: I wrote these two rules in a row (first redirects to a folder on a subdomain, and then transform to the subdomain www), but when you type url **domain.com/subdomain** URL in browser looks like: **http://www.domain.com/http://domain.com/home/account/www/site/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/**

Comment: @Makigator there must be an other conflicting rule. First try only these rules as I posted them. Then if it works try to build from there, inserting your other rules one-by-one.

Comment: I wrote only a rule to redirect a folder to a subdomain on localhost and got the same result ...

Comment: The `home/account/www/` part is definitely NOT coming from my rules. I suspect they come from a misused `REQUEST_FILENAME`.

Comment: Sorry, the file does have guidelines:
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI}! \. (Png | jpg | jpeg | gif) $ [NC]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-D
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php / $ 1 [QSA] These rules are listed at the end

Comment: Please add these code samples to the end of your question, as it is pretty hard to read them in a coment.

Comment: Added to the end of the issue

Comment: Isert my rules (the subdomain ones) directly after the `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: put, if you come to a subdomain - error 500, in the folder - the same redirect `home/account/www/`