# .htaccess subdomain creation

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

What folders do I create if I use the following code in .htaccess? I'm attempting to build a website making site but the subdomain creation part is stumping me, here's the code:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}$1
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com(.*) /subdomains/$1/$2

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomains
#RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}$1
#RewriteRule user/a.x /subdomains/index.php?a.x

#--------------
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule user/(.*)/(.*) showpage.php?user=$1&page=$2 [nc]
```

so would it be a user folder? a subdomains folder? confused :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com $ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/ [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^domain.com $|^www.domain.com $) [NC]
RewriteRule ^\.*$ /error.html [L]
```

This would be robust... but maybe it could be done better?

Another answer can be is listed here:
[htaccess subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain)