# .htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We are creating a site replication system where users will be able to create subdomains on our site and that's all working already.

So, a user can come in and create

```
http://siteid.ourwebsite.com
```

The problem is we also want offer users an aditional URL for their site which is: `http://ourwebsite.com/siteid`. Now, this will be the same as their subdomain.

The only way I see this possible is via .htaccess.

Good thing... we only have index.php file in the root. So, if there is anything else it can be considered a subdomain.

So, can we create a rule in .htaccess file that if a user is trying to access anything which is not ending with `.php` it redirects them to `http://$VAR.ourwebsite.com` where `$VAR` is what they are trying to access?

Does that sound possible?

Comment: So do you just want the `siteid.ourwebsite.com` to be an alias of `ourwebsite.com/siteid`?

Comment: would this post be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain

Comment: Hi - we just want a external redirect and not any alias or something. the link you gave is also doing an internal redirect for virtual hosts which we dont' need. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.

this does the job.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.domain.com [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

Comment: Once question though, the above code is only working for a .com domain and not any .net or .org domain... any reason why this might be happening.

Comment: Figured it out! i had the .htaccess file chmoded 600 but it needs to be 644. all working well now.