# Create a fake subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I'm confuse, how to make a fake subdomain,

let's say I want to make a fake subdomain like

http://subdomain.example.com/category/my-url-category

but that fake subdomain read data from

http://www.example.com/category/my-url-category

I'm using CI as my framework, and I've try on the .htaccess like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/subdomain/category/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

But it's not work

Thanks in advance

Comment: these other 'so' questions may be useful: **[htaccess-subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain)**, **[Create Subdomains on the fly with .htaccess (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586129/create-subdomains-on-the-fly-with-htaccess-php)**

Answer (score 0):

For subdomains to work, you'll need to change your dns to translate said subdomain to your site. This is done with a CNAME record. Typically your DNS looks something like this:

```
Domain           Type       Target
example.com      A          192.168.1.0
*.example.com    CNAME      example.com
```

`*.example.com` will route `this.example.com` and `that.example.com` to the ip defined for `example.com`, but `this.other.example.com` is not matched by it. If you just want to have one subdomain, make a CNAME record for just that subdomain instead (not with a *).

---

In httpd.conf (this is the main config file for Apache, might be named differently on your operating system) make sure your subdomains are using the same document root. I am not familiar with this, but [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) might help according to [this](http://www.calcatraz.com/blog/wildcard-subdomains-in-apache-1422).

---

In .htaccess in your www-root have the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/subdomain/category/%1/$1
```

This will internally rewrite `somename.example.com/whatever/thing` to `DOCUMENT_ROOT/index.php/subdomain/category/somename/whatever/thing`.