# URL rewriting for sub-domains

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a couple of sub-domains in addition to my main domain. Like so: domain.com, about.domain.com and new.domain.com.

All 3 have their own .htaccess file in their individual root folders.

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. all traffic gets routed to the same URL respectively.
2. the URL thankyou.php gets rewritten to /thank-you

Both of these work for the main domain, domain.com.

But they do not work for the sub-domains.

Here is what works for domain.com:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/

RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteRule    ^thank-you/?$    thankyou.php    [NC,L]
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain

Comment: Thanx for the response. I looked at it but had no idea what to do with it. Sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: first of all, are you able to access the subdomain without the extra parameters in the url?

Comment: @alex If I use a separate .htaccess file in the root directory of the sub-domain then I cannot access any pages of the sub-domain. But, I do not have a separate .htaccess file in the root of the sub-domain then I can at least get to the pages just fine. But the "rewrite rule for the thankyou.php page" is not working as it is inserting an extra slash in the front, like so:  /about.domain.com/thank-you

Comment: What do you mean by `all traffic gets routed to the same URL respectively.`?

Comment: @anubhava domain.com, domain.com/index.php, www.domain.com, www.domain.com/index.php all gets routed to the one standardized URL: www.domain.com This works for my main domain name just fine with the current rules that are in the .htaccess file.

Comment: ok how does a similar subdomain URL look like? Is it `www.sub.domain.com/index.php`? What is DocumentRoot path of your sub domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this .htaccess for your sub domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\s
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^thank-you/?$ /thankyou.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanx for the response.  So does this go in a separate .htaccess file that resides in the root for the sub-domain..??

Comment: When I added it to a .htaccess file in the root of the sub-domain, every time I wanted to go to about.domain.com it took me to an error page with the URL www.about.domain.com

Comment: Ok then probably you don't have www.About setup. Comment out first tulle and retest or see update.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can now get to the regular pages. The only part that is not working is the rule for the "Thank You page". If I try to access about.domain.com/thank-you/ it give me an error page with this URL:  /about.domain.com/about.domain.com/thankyou.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this yet?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (about)(/.*|$) $1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where should I put this..?? In the .htaccess file that is in my root of the main domain name...?? Should I place this at the bottom of what I have so far that is working for the main domain name as I have shown in my original post...??

Comment: Ok, nothing is working if I put it in the .htaccess files for the individual subdomains.  But, if I add it to the bottom of what I already have working in the .htaccess file for the main domain, it does work for displaying the individual pages but the rewriting of the "Thank You" URL (thankyou.php) does not work as it inserts a leading slash at the beginning, like so:  /about.domain.com/thank-you