# htaccess need name in front of domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i have a file named page.php, which has 2 get variables. the u and edit so at the moment i have

```
mysite.com/page.php?u=dan &
mysite.com/page.php?u=dan&edit
```

But how can i make the url look like this using htaccess?

```
dan.mysite.com &
dan.mysite.com/edit
```

At the moment i have tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?u=$1
```

but this just makes

```
mysite.com/dan
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here (for example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?u=dan&$1 [L,QSA]
```