# Redirect folders to subdomains using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect

```
www.example.com/mydomain?data1=value1&data2=value2
```

to

```
mydomain.example.com/?data1=value1&data2=value2
```

I want to redirect with the PHP variables passed to it.

How do I do that with the .htaccess file? I am sorry if this is answered elsewhere, I can't find it with search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess subdomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445978/htaccess-subdomain)

Comment: @sobolevn will it work with variables passed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward rewrite, but...

...you need to know about the `mod_rewrite` *Query String Append Flag* (`[QSA]`):

The `mod_rewrite` rule to add to the root folder of `www.example.com` is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) http://$1.example.com [R=301,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your public_html/.htaccess, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydomain/?$ http://mydomain.example.com/ [NC,QSA,L,R]
```

This will redirect

```
http://example.com/mydomain?query_strings
```

to

```
http://mydomain.example.com/?query_strings
```